# About Jeju Island visas

Tags: visas, south-korea, pakistani-citizens, jeju

I am planning to visit to Jeju Island, Korea, for vacation (5 to 6 days). Is there any specific visa requirement for me because I'm traveling also to Singapore, Macau or the Philippines from Pakistan?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: I'm Pakistani citizen

Answer (score 8):

Republic of Korea Ministry of Justice has a new restriction on Jeju Visa-Free entry, restricting visa-free status to 12 additional countries, effective August 1, 2018.

- Bangladesh
- Egypt (Effective Sept. 1, 2018)
- Cameroon
- Gambia
- Kyrgyzstan
- Myanmar
- Nepal
- **Pakistan**
- Senegal
- Somalia
- Sri Lanka
- Uzbekistan
- [source - sorry, Korean](http://www.moj.go.kr/HP/COM/bbs_03/ListShowData.do?strNbodCd=noti0003&strWrtNo=5177&strAnsNo=A&strRtnURL=MOJ_30600000&strOrgGbnCd=100000) ([pdf version by Korea Embassy in Beijing, Korean too](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/cn-ko/brd/m_1237/view.do?seq=1346728&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1))

Since you are Pakistan citizen, you need a visa to enter Jeju Island and the mainland Korea. (PS: Single entry visa is sufficient to visit Jeju island and the mainland.)

Comment: Could you list all twelve countries? Until the information is available in other languages, it could be useful.

Comment: @Giorgio - done!

Comment: This answer is strangely worded. 'Visa-free entry is restricted to X, Y, and Z' means only X, Y, and Z may enter visa-free. This answer says the opposite.

Comment: @jcm You always have an option to 'edit'.

Comment: @revi true, but I can't read the source.

Answer (score 2):

[This list of countries](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10) shows that Pakistan citizens do not need a visa to visit Jeju for up to 30 days.

You cannot visit other places in Korea without a visa.

[Please go upvote revi's answer, it's more up to date].

Comment: I'm Pakistani citizen, I wanna visit to Jeju Island only, jeju island visa feer entry for pakistani citizen??